# How do I reverse an itertools.chain object?

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

My function creates a chain of generators:

```
def bar(num):
    import itertools
    some_sequence = (x*1.5 for x in range(num))
    some_other_sequence = (x*2.6 for x in range(num))
    chained = itertools.chain(some_sequence, some_other_sequence)
    return chained
```

My function sometimes needs to return `chained` in reversed order. Conceptually, the following is what I would like to be able to do:

```
if num < 0:
    return reversed(chained)
return chained
```

Unfortunately:

```
>>> reversed(chained)
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence
```

What are my options?

This is in some realtime graphic rendering code so I don't want to make it too complicated/slow.

**EDIT**:
When I first posed this question I hadn't thought about the reversibility of generators. As many have pointed out, generators can't be reversed.

I do in fact want to reverse the flattened contents of the chain; not just the order of the generators.

Based on the responses, there is no single call I can use to reverse an itertools.chain, so I think the only solution here is to use a list, at least for the reverse case, and perhaps for both.

Comment: Hm, I would have thought `itertools.islice` with a negative step would have worked, but it turns out only positive values are valid for that arg to `islice`.  Interesting question.

Comment: It’s not just `chained`, it’s your generators:
`>>> reversed((x for x in range(5)))`
`TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence`

Comment: @jleedev Good point; generators can't be reversed even if there is a way to reverse an itertools.chain. I hadn't realized that before but understand it now. However, reversed also doesn't work on an itertools.chain that is composed exclusively of lists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if num < 0:
    lst = list(chained)
    lst.reverse()
    return lst
else:
    return chained
```

`reversed()` needs an actual sequence, because it iterates it backwards by index, and that wouldn't work for a generator (which only has the notion of "next" item).

Since you will need to unroll the whole generator anyway for reversing, the most efficient way is to read it to a list and reverse the list in-place with the `.reverse()` method.

Comment: Yes, but it is necessary to exhaust the generator if you need to access the last item in the general case (which is implied by reversing). Without seeing the real code, it's impossible to provide a better solution.

Comment: @Ant As shang, Jochen Ritzel, and others brought up, generators can't be reversed without exhausting them anyway. I hadn't considered that when I posed the original question. At least shang's solution only unrolls the generators for the num < 0 condition.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot reverse generators by definition. The interface of a generator is the iterator, which is a container that supports only forward iteration. When you want to reverse a iterator, you have to collect all it's items first and reverse them after that.

Use lists instead or generate the sequences backwards from the start.

Answer (score 4):

itertools.chain would need to implement `__reversed__()` (this would be best) or `__len__()` and `__getitem__()`

Since it doesn't, and there's not even a way to access the internal sequences you'll need to expand the entire sequence to be able to reverse it.

```
reversed(list(CHAIN_INSTANCE))
```

It would be nice if chain would make `__reversed__()` available when all the sequences are reversable, but currently it does not do that. Perhaps you can write your own version of chain that does

Answer (score 1):

```
def reversed2(iter):
    return reversed(list(iter))
```

Answer (score 0):

`reversed` only works on objects that support `len` and indexing. You have to first generate all results of a generator before wrapping `reversed` around them.

However, you could easily do this:

```
def bar(num):
    import itertools
    some_sequence = (x*1.5 for x in range(num, -1, -1))
    some_other_sequence = (x*2.6 for x in range(num, -1, -1))
    chained = itertools.chain(some_other_sequence, some_sequence)
    return chained
```

Comment: Objects that implement `__reversed__` also will work with `reversed()`: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__

Answer (score 0):

Does this work in you real app?

```
def bar(num):
    import itertools
    some_sequence = (x*1.5 for x in range(num))
    some_other_sequence = (x*2.6 for x in range(num))
    list_of_chains = [some_sequence, some_other_sequence]
    if num < 0:
        list_of_chains.reverse()
    chained = itertools.chain(*list_of_chains)
    return chained
```

Comment: This reverses the order of the sequences in the chain, not the  sequences themselves.  `L1 = [1,2,3]; L2 = [4,5,6]` chain these two and reverse the result and it's `[6,5,4,3,2,1]`, with your solution it'd be `[4,5,6,1,2,3]`, no?

Comment: i think it is what the op meant..there is no way to reverse the order of the values returned by a generator without exhaust it...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't considered that generators couldn't be reversed when I posed the original question, so in fact I would like to reverse the flattened contents of the chain rather than the order of generators in the chain itself.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can't because chained objects may even contain infinite sequences such as `itertools.count(...)`.

You should try to reverse your generators/sequences or use `reversed(iterable)` for each sequence if applicable and then chain them together last-to-first. Of course this highly depends on your use case.